# Google maps in flutter applications

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter

Hey I wanted to ask if there is a way to use the google maps api in the flutter application. I want to avoid using the static maps. Please let me know if there is a way.

Answer (score 7):

Inline maps support is covered in [issue 73](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73). It's not implemented yet, but it's in the current milestone.

You can use the [location](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location) plugin to get the current geolocation.

Comment: Is there any way through which I can get the geolocation of the user?

Comment: I also want to display the map and I am thinking of doing that through native maps but my doubt is how do I return the map??