# How to add a Google Maps view to Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I've been tasked to build an app but it requires that I have a map view. Only issue is, there isn't the greatest support for maps using Flutter (If any).
I just wanted to find out from anyone if they know any good map plugins for flutter that are available.

Comment: There is an official plugin work-in-progress https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_mobile_maps and also one or more 3rd-party plugins are available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340522/map-view-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340522/map-view-in-flutter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps in flutter applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952140/google-maps-in-flutter-applications)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map View in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340522/map-view-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no official support for this. Everything is still in development. There are some 3rd party options but most do not allow things like overlays and layer implementation. I am currently also creating an app that requires uploading of a kmz file from google earth. The option I have taken is creating an android channel and using the traditional Java api, see https://flutter.io/platform-channels/

Answer (score 0):

Flutter team working for native map_view. But for the time you can use map_view: "^0.0.12". 
I found a simple implementation of google map [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/07/flutter-with-google-map.html).

Answer (score 0):

An official flutter plugin for google maps exists. It can be found [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter).

The current version is 2.0. Which supports layers, markers, info windows, current position and more. It does not support polylines, polygons or tap events. There are a number of pull requests with this functionality.